# Python; how to start an interpreter from a python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python file and within that file I want to start an interpreter within that context. Is that possible?

I'm currently starting an interpreter and then using `exec` to load in the file, but it would be quicker and easier to do it the other way around.

The use case is loading in a file full of data and helper functions that I then want to play around with in the interpreter.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to interpret exactly, and why, and how…?

Comment: @deceze I've added a little more detail but I'm not sure what you're looking for exactly.

Comment: What you most likely want to do is do it other way round. Run an interpreter and from that import your script to fill the namespace with whatever you need.

Comment: @matszwecja That's what I'm currently doing, but it would be quicker and easier the other way around.

Comment: Call `python -i file.py`, __-i__ will make you stay in the interpreter

Comment: or use the evil `eval()`. joad up you pip config in the current interpreter and then put an eval block around it all, quite fast but prone to injection.

Comment: @matszwecja thanks that works! post as an answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-i` flag when running Python interpreter makes you stay in the interpreter after script finishes running.

```
python -i file.py
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-i` flag might be what you are looking for.  From `man python`:

```
-i     When  a  script is passed as first argument or the -c option is used, enter interactive mode after executing the script or
       the command.  It does not read the $PYTHONSTARTUP file.  This can be useful to inspect global variables or a  stack  trace
       when a script raises an exception.
```

So for example, `python -i my_script.py` will run `my_script.py`, then leave you in an interactive session inside the same interpreter once the script completes.